# Glassfish 4.1, JPA EntityManager Null Pointer Exception

Tags: jsp, jpa, glassfish

I have a bit weird issue with one Glassfish-Server and no idea any more, where to look for.

On Ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS, Glassfish 4.1, OpenJDK 1.7 (or Oracle JDK 1.8) I get the following exception on accessing the mysql-database:

```
[2016-03-18T20:44:16.693+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00024] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1458330256693] [levelValue: 800] [[
Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.grizzly.config.dom.Ssl]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:16.720+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1458330256720] [levelValue: 800] [[
SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@4e5ce39d]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:16.720+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-JMX-00020] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1458330256720] [levelValue: 900] [[
All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:16.744+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1458330256744] [levelValue: 800] [[
SSLParams =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@4e5ce39d]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:16.744+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [NCLS-JMX-00020] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1458330256744] [levelValue: 900] [[
All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using SSL implementation specific defaults]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:16.810+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00025] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1458330256810] [levelValue: 800] [[
SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL: ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:17.024+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1458330257024] [levelValue: 800] [[
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@46fa75c6 as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@25eb5807.]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:17.203+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330257203] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:18.369+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=71 _ThreadName=Thread-23] [timeMillis: 1458330258369] [levelValue: 800] [[
JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://ownNas:8686/jndi/rmi://ownNas:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:19.166+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330259166] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:19.177+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330259177] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:19.180+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330259180] [levelValue: 800] [[
visiting unvisited references]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:21.610+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330261610] [levelValue: 800] [[
Initializing Mojarra 2.2.12 ( 20150720-0848 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.12@14885) for context '']]

[2016-03-18T20:44:22.885+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330262885] [levelValue: 800] [[
Loading application [__admingui] at [/]]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:22.887+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00022] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=74 _ThreadName=Thread-25] [timeMillis: 1458330262887] [levelValue: 800] [[
Loading application __admingui done in 5,865 ms]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:39.877+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.default] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1458330279877] [levelValue: 900] [[

2016-03-18 20:44:39 http-listener-1(4)  INFO  com.np.propmgmt.controller.HouseController: ejbFacade com.np.propmgmt.facade.HouseFacade@29b9cef7
2016-03-18 20:44:39 http-listener-1(4)  INFO  com.np.propmgmt.facade.HouseFacade: em-manager com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper@2969d5d3

java.lang.NullPointerException
      at org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.ServerPlatformUtils.createServerPlatform(ServerPlatformUtils.java:99)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.init(SessionManager.java:77)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.factories.SessionManager.<clinit>(SessionManager.java:71)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.addSessionToGlobalSessionManager(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:907)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.initSession(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:2671)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:675)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:205)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:305)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:337)
      at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:318)
      at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper._getDelegate(EntityManagerWrapper.java:197)
      at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerWrapper.java:521)
      at com.np.propmgmt.facade.HouseFacade.findAll(HouseFacade.java:72)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
      at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
      at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
      at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
      at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
      at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
      at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
      at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
      at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy182.findAll(Unknown Source)
      at com.np.propmgmt.facade.__EJB31_Generated__HouseFacade__Intf____Bean__.findAll(Unknown Source)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:434)
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
      at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
      at com.np.propmgmt.facade.HouseFacade$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findAll(Unknown Source)
      at com.np.propmgmt.controller.HouseController.getItems(HouseController.java:104)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
      at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
      at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
      at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:363)
      at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
      at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
      at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:140)
      at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:204)
      at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
      at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
      at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
      at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
      at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
      at javax.faces.component.UISelectItems.getValue(UISelectItems.java:129)
      at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getSelectItems(InputRenderer.java:54)
      at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeMarkup(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:73)
      at org.primefaces.component.selectonemenu.SelectOneMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(SelectOneMenuRenderer.java:67)
      at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)
      at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
      at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:176)
      at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:890)
      at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
      at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
      at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)
      at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)
      at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)
      at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:337)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
      at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
      at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
      at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
      at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
      at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
      at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
      at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
]]

[2016-03-18T20:44:39.918+0100] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.eclipse.persistence.session./file:/usr/share/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/PropertyMgmt-2.0/WEB-INF/classes/_com.np.propmgmt] [tid: _ThreadID=26 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(4)] [timeMillis: 1458330279918] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258]]
```

On Windows 10 (or Debian 7.8), Glassfish 4.1 (build 13), JDK 1.7 (or 1.8) everything is working. I am bit helpless, where I can look for.

HouseController:

```
package com.np.propmgmt.controller;

import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.DocumentTreeNode;
import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.EntryCode;
import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.EntryCodeAmounts;
import com.np.propmgmt.facade.HouseFacade;
import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.House;
import com.np.propmgmt.util.JsfUtil;
import com.np.propmgmt.util.NavigationBean;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.event.ValueChangeEvent;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.primefaces.event.NodeSelectEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.DefaultTreeNode;
import org.primefaces.model.TreeNode;



@Named("houseController")
@SessionScoped
public class HouseController extends AbstractController<House> implements Serializable {

    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @Inject
    private HouseFacade        ejbFacade;

    @Inject
    private NavigationBean     navBean;

    private int                houseId     = 0;
    private TreeNode           entryCodeRoot;

    private int                entryCodeId;
    private BigDecimal         ecAmountFix;
    private BigDecimal         ecAmountVar;
    private Date               ecValidFrom;
    private Date               ecValidThru;


    public HouseController() {
        super(House.class);
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        super.setFacade(ejbFacade);
    }

    @Override
     public void setSelected(House selected) {
        if (selected == null)
             return;

        super.setSelected( selected );
        if (this.houseId != selected.getHouseId())
            this.entryCodeId = 0;

        this.houseId = selected.getHouseId();
    }

    public void houseChanged(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        if (event.getNewValue() != getSelected()) {
            setSelected(null);
        }
    }

    public List<House> getItems() {
        logger.info("ejbFacade " + ejbFacade);
        return ejbFacade.findAll();
    }


}
```

HouseFacade:

```
package com.np.propmgmt.facade;

import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.EntryCode;
import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.EntryCodeAmounts;
import com.np.propmgmt.entity.tables.House;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

@Stateless
public class HouseFacade extends AbstractFacade<House> {
    private final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "com.np.propmgmt")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public HouseFacade() {
        super(House.class);
    }

    public House findHouse (int p_house)
    {
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().
                      createNamedQuery("House.findByHouseId")
                     .setParameter("houseId", p_house);
        return (House) q.getSingleResult();
    }    

        public List<EntryCode> findHouseEntryCodes (
                 int houseId) {
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().
                      createNamedQuery("EntryCode.findByHouse").setParameter("houseId", houseId);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public List<House> findAll() {
        logger.info("em-manager " + getEntityManager());
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().
                      createNamedQuery("House.findAll");
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public List<EntryCodeAmounts> findHouseEcAmounts (
                    int entryCodeId) {
        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().
                      createNamedQuery("EntryCodeAmounts.findByEntryCodeId").setParameter("entryCodeId", entryCodeId);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public void newEcAmounts (
                int        entryCodeId,
                BigDecimal amountFix,
                BigDecimal amountVar,
                Date       validFrom,
                Date       validThru) {

        javax.persistence.Query q = getEntityManager().
                      createNamedQuery("EntryCodeAmounts.terminateLast").
                        setParameter("entryCodeId", entryCodeId).
                        setParameter("validThru", validFrom);
        q.executeUpdate();

        EntryCodeAmounts ecAmounts = new EntryCodeAmounts();
        ecAmounts.setEntryCodeId(entryCodeId);
        ecAmounts.setAmountVar(amountVar);
        ecAmounts.setAmountFix(amountFix);
        ecAmounts.setValidFrom(validFrom);
        ecAmounts.setValidThru(validThru);
        getEntityManager().persist(ecAmounts);
    }
}
```

All other access to other tables/entity-classes are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are hititng https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-21468 which is just a warning that can be ignored.  This NPE occurs when the persistence unit is deployed, which only occurs the first time it is accessed. and caught and logged by the server platform detection method, which then proceeds with deployment normally.

Comment: Yes it looks like the same, but in my case, it seems to "destroy" the internal structures. I copied over GF from the Debian-Srv and now everything is working.
thx Nik